# Getting click event on parent page of button in frame

Tags: jquery, html, iframe, onclick

I am stuck to one situation.I have a Parent JSP page in which i am calling an i frame where different domain URL is getting  called. Now i want that in i frame there is button called logout with an id:

```
<input type="button" id="logout" value="Logout">
```

Now this button resides in I frame, I want click event on my parent page.

Any help.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0):

try document.parent to select your parent document